# what does %pip mean?

Tags: python, pip

I see this is a notebook file:

```
%pip install wordcloud
```

I would usually do: `pip install wordcloud` without the `%`.

I have tried looking this up, but cannot seem to find it.
What does the `%` actually do ? is it notebook specific ?

**EDIT**:
there are 4 proposed solutions (that were similar).
it appears as though the `%` is a replacement in the notebook for `cmd`, but this does not explain its usage, in particular this:

> so the `%` effectively replaces the `cmd` ? but i dont get why it is used
> given that the pip command is only needed to be run once ? is it proposed that this
> pip is run every time (to install the latest version)...

So:  **why use %pip in place of pip install?**, what is the benefit ?

Comment: to the best of my understanding, this is indeed notebook specific, as you pointed out. anyway, I doubt python interpreter would ever recognize `pip` command

Comment: These are not notebook specific, it is an ipython magic: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pip

Comment: The rationale for adding a %pip magic is discussed here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11524

Answer (score 0):

This is a so called "magic" command and specific to the ipython kernel for jupyter notebooks.

You can read more about it here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Comment: so the `%` effectively replaces the `cmd` ?  but i dont get why it is used given that the `pip` command is only run once ?  is it proposed that this pip is run every time (to install the latest version)....  ?